# overriding toString() representation of object returns unexpected symbol

Tags: java, junit, junit4, tostring, primitive-types

I'm writing a JUnit test method for a Clock class to ensure that the toString representation of the object returns in the format that I want it to. So, I've overriden the toString() and written it as it want it to be represented but when I compare it with the format I expect in JUnit it fails with the following:

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected: < Time : 10:0[0:0]0 > but was:< Time : 10:0[:]0>

Why is the symbols [ and ] being displayed here? Is it some part of the toString() representation which I do not know about? Relevant code is below:

**JUnit:**

```
    @Test
public void testFormattingOfTimeIsDisplayedCorrectly() {

    final byte TEN = 10;
    final byte DBL_ZERO = 00;

    clock.setTime(TEN, DBL_ZERO, DBL_ZERO);

    final String EXPECTED_STRING = "Time : 10:00:00";

    assertEquals(EXPECTED_STRING, clock.toString());    

}
```

**toString() in Clock class:**

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Time : " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

**and the setTime method also in Clock class:**

```
public void setTime(byte hour, byte minutes, byte seconds) {

    this.hours = hour;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.seconds = seconds;

}
```

I'm wondering, maybe it has something to do with using byte? Or is it just something with what toString() returns that I don't understand. I'm just puzzled about why my JUnit method don't see them as the same format.

Comment: the [ ] simbols are just put for assertion output (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace by the line:

```
return "Time : " + String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds);
```

Comment: Why not `return String.format("Time : %02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)`?

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
<10:0[0:0]0 > but was:< Time : 10:0[:]0>
```

is indicating the difference. i.e. the output is 10:0:0 as opposed to 10:00:00. Not surprising, given that your code does this:

```
return "Time : " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

and the minutes/econds aren't zero-padded. Perhaps check out `String.format()` with a `%02d` format setting. I don't understand (also) why you'd use byte for the values. An `int` would be a much more normal type to use here.

Comment: Ah I see. I just changed the EXPECTED_STRING to:
final String EXPECTED_STRING = "Time : 10:0:0";

and the test passed. But I want to have the padded zeroes, so I will check out String.format() as you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's pointing out that your method returns 10:0:0 instead of 10:00:00. Numeric types don't store leading zeros so your DBL_ZERO constant doesn't work in the way you want.

Try this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Time : " + hours + ":"
        + (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":"
        + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
}
```